# Why Spark Streaming output results Until interrupting the programme?

Tags: apache-spark

When I run the wordcount example code in the spark, the program don't print any result in the console. When I interrupt the program using CTRL + C, the result will print on the console. I use spark in local model, don't know why? Anybody can give some suggestions?

code:

```
object KafkaWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 4) {
      System.err.println("Usage: KafkaWordCount <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()

    val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

    val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L))
      .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)
    wordCounts.print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: When I change the print() to saveAsTextFile(), the program don't save any result file. But when I interrupt the program, It will appear many result files.

Comment: How long do you let it run? I'd reduce the 10 minutes in the `windowDuration`.